# Error importing seaborn module in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I'm trying to use the seaborn module in jupyter notebook,I alredy installed all the dependecies and the seaborn too,but when I try to run,it's said that it does not have a module seaborn installed

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ed806232820c> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 3 import seaborn as sns

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn'
```

Comment: Have you tried looking up for that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restarting notebook first.

Make sure that `seaborn` is installed by same python interpreter used in the notebook.

Easiest way to be certain of this is to run
`!pip install --user seaborn` in the active notebook (`!` allows you to run shell command from your notebook)

---

Additional info for detecting the cause of the problem

You can check which interpreter is used by the notebook by running:

```
import sys

print(sys.executable)
```

I assume `pip` you used initially is not used by python you used to run the notebook (multiple python installations of the system or conda).

To specify which python is used for `pip install` you can run
`<python-path> -m pip install seaborn` where `<python-path>` is output of `sys.executable`.

Comment: I used the !pip install --user seaborn and worked very well,thanks